# How to use awk when calling from python?

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to execute a bash script with python e.g. I have to go through all of the commands and try to call them in a python script.

I have problems to do one specific, and I believe it is due to the fact that I have low bash knowledge.

```
subprocess.run("awk -v offset=\""+offset+"\"\'NR==1{old11=-offset; old7=0; next} {print strtonum(\"0x\" $11)-old11\",\"($7-old7)/1000000000; old11=strtonum(\"0x\" $11); old7=$7}\'"+ path2saveOutput+name+"-file", shell=True, stdout=open(path2saveOutput+name+"-file.mat", 'a'))
```

I get an error

> Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ...
>   Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] [--] 'program' file ...

I guess I am missing some parameters in my command line!?

Comment: Can you print the parameter value inside the subprocess.run?  Let us see what is your actual awk command.  Thanks..   print awk -v offset=\""+offset+"\"\'NR==1{old11=-offset; old7=0; next} {print strtonum(\"0x\" $11)-old11\",\"($7-old7)/1000000000; old11=strtonum(\"0x\" $11); old7=$7}\'"+ path2saveOutput+name+"-file"

Comment: Can you make a script that uses the parameters `offset` and `outputfile`, and calls `awk`?

Comment: It would be much easier if you used a list as the argument to `subprocess.run()` instead of trying to concatenate everything into a string.

Comment: But why do you need to use `awk` in the first place? What can it do that you can't do in Python directly?